# Does the sudo user need a home directory?

Tags: debian, sudo

In my setup, my aim is to have

1. A standard user with minimal permissions to use on a daily basis
2. A superuser account, defined in `/etc/sudoers`.

Does this second user need a home directory? Both of these users will be created by a `tempsudo` account, which is created during the installation step. I'll delete this account once account #2 is created with this command:

```
sudo adduser --no-create-home permsudo
```

Will I run into problems in a graphical environment, e.g. with `gksudo`? I'm using Linux Mint Debian, so I will be running a desktop environment.

Comment: "A user granted all permissions...to perform system maintenance tasks" == `root`.  Creating a user who's privileges match root but isn't root *is not safer*, if anything, it is probably *worse*.  There is a superuser account, use that.  `root`'s home is `/root`, yes it needs one, and yes root can use a GUI (you may have to configure your display manager, if you use one, to allow this).  Just don't use a web browser or other network client there.

Comment: @goldilocks I edited the question, since I meant a superuser account.

Comment: The "superuser" IS root.  That's who "root" is. `superuser` == `root`.  "superuser" and "root" are synonymous. You don't have to create another superuser -- it makes no sense.  A user who can do anything cannot be compartmentalized from another user who can also do everything, so (to repeat) having two of them is pointless, confusing, etc.  There is inevitably, by necessity a root account, root's home is `/root`.  Have a look (you need superuser permissions to do so...).  You can log in as `root`, use a GUI, do maintenance, etc.  The account ALREADY EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required for this auxiliary sudo user to have a home directory.

There are no obvious problems from this approach, but you won't have any default GUI settings, so if these are important, you should make a home directory and lock it down.  If you are going to login and use this user via GUI, you should probably make sure it looks different from your normal user so it is obvious when you have the tools to break the box.

Comment: There is an obvious problem with this in so far as a non-root account with root privileges can potentially screw with the root -- which will lead to nothing good and has no advantages.  Do not do this.  If you want to be the superuser, *just be the superuser and log in as root*.

Comment: To state this is an obvious problem is equivalent to stating the sudo command should not exist.  So, this is not an obvious problem, it is a preference.

Comment: The point of sudo is to grant users *limited* privileges.  I'm just pointing all this out because it seems to me the OP is confused or unaware of the purpose of the root account.  If not and I look like a loudmouth fool, that's fine -- I'm not trying to criticize your answer beyond raising a caveat.

Comment: I think it was fairly clear his intention was to make an account to handle routine system maintenance jobs that was not root, so he was not bound to logging in as root to accomplish them.  If that was not the intention, your criticism is vastly more appropriate.

Comment: @goldilocks I appreciate the correction. I don't know too much about Unix at the moment, and I had some terminology mixed up.

Comment: Of course the user has to have a home directory, or you couldn't log in as this user in the first place, so you couldn't run `sudo`.  Also you know when you have the power to break the box not because of who you are logged in as, but because you *ran* `sudo` to obain that power.

Comment: @psusi : Wrong...that's not what determines whether you can log in or not (it's what your login shell, as listed in /etc/passwd, does).  You can log in without a $HOME.  You start in `/`.

Comment: @goldilocks, well, you *can* login without a home directory, but you get a very broken session.  Not having a home directory on your account would be stupid and pointless and points to a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on.

Comment: @psusi : I agree that it is pointless and the OP did admit his limited understanding above.  Just it is not *impossible*.  You could put up an answer explaining why having a $HOME is an important, pragmatically essential thing for login users, I'd upvote for that.  Without testing, I suspect a homeless user with write permissions on `/` may end up creating some clutter.

Comment: -1 for this answer as it encourages the OP to go ahead with this horror, and proposes a broken solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are confused. There is an account on the system, called `root`, who has an account (and a home, traditionally `/root`). It is all-powerful, and by analogy to other systems it is also called the "superuser". The command `su(1)` allows one user to start a shell as another user (substitute), and he command `sudo(1)` allows an user to run commands with the privileges of another user, in a controlled manner (the file `/etc/sudoers` contains the configuration, see `sudoers(5)`). `sudo` is typically used to allow regular users to run a limited range of commands as `root`.